# Which Reformation theologians used the analogy of water and ink for sin?

Tags: sin, nature-of-man, reformation

On page 98 of [Miroslav Volf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miroslav_Volf)'s [Free of Charge: Giving and Forgiving](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0310265746), he says:

> But even if all of us are sinners from head to toe, none of us is a
>   sinner through and through, with nothing good remaining in us. As
>   sinners, we are still God's good creatures. **To illustrate the
>   relationship between being a good creature and being a sinner,
>   Reformation theologians used the analogy of water and ink. Water is
>   the good creation, ink is sin, and the sinner is a glass of water with
>   a few drops of ink. All the water in the glass is tainted, but it's
>   still mostly water, not ink.** Analogously, all our good deeds are
>   marred by sin, but they are still mostly good deeds, not crimes
>   masquerading as merits. Now apply this to gifts. We give gifts. None
>   of them are pure. Yet with all their impurities, many of them are
>   still genuine gifts, not just hidden ways of loving ourselves.

There is no footnote. Who is Volf most likely referring to? What is the original context(s)?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say Luther is the most likely candidate. However, a [search of water+ink at CCEL](http://www.ccel.org/search/fulltext/water+ink) turned up nothing. The closest result was [a passage in Calvin's *Institutes*](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/calvin/institutes.v.xii.html?highlight=water,ink#highlight), talking about how the cuttlefish hides by squirting ink into the water.

Comment: I emailed Volf himself and he replied tersely: "Calvin. Don't know exactly where. Poke around" I think it's possible he's mistaken that it was Calvin, and perhaps even mistaken that *any* Reformation theologian used it. I don't think there's any chance he had the cuttle-fish thing in mind either, since they're talking about very different things and Calvin doesn't even say "ink" but "inky blood."

Comment: This is the oldest use of the example I could find: https://books.google.nl/books?id=jBbJa8pOlRoC&lpg=PA73&ots=SowNTzpa6e&dq=sin%20like%20ink%20glass%20of%20water&pg=PA73#v=onepage&q&f=false Interestingly it's also being used (in Dutch) by someone on an Islamic forum...

Answer (score 4):

Expanding the search a bit to account for polluting agents other than ink, the closest I can find in Calvin is in his commentary on Isaiah 1, referring to the line in v. 22 that he translates as ["Thy silver is become dross, thy wine mixed with water"](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/calvin/calcom13.viii.i.html).

Even here though, the sense is not the same as what Volf is going for; Calvin says that the image is one of hypocrisy:

> The comparisons here employed are exceedingly well adapted to this end, for dross bears some resemblance to gold; and in like manner, the color of wine mixed with water resembles that of pure wine; and yet both are very far from having that purity of which they make an outward show. In like manner hypocrites, by their hypocrisy, may be said to assume a false color of silver, though they are of no more value than dross.

Comment: That's definitely the closest one yet.